# How to select column based on condition in row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df, and want to select only the columns that have a specific value "xyz" in row [0].

I know if I were trying to select rows with a specific value "xyz" in column [0] I would just do:

```
df[df[0] == 'xyz']
```

Now I try:

```
df[df.loc[0] == 'xyz']
```

and I get error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Why won't the same operation work for selecting columns with a condition? And what's the easiest solution to get just the columns I want?

Comment: ``df[]`` is a convenient way to access data via the columns. If however, you want to select values based on a row condition, you need to use ``df.loc[df.loc[0] == 'xyz']`` -> this lets Pandas know that you want to select on the rows. Pandas then aligns the boolean Series with the dataframe to return an output

Comment: @sammywemmy I get error ```IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match```

Comment: ``df.loc[:,df.loc[0]=="xyz"]`` ? This however will select on the columns. Kindly share some data

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output that helps a lot.

Comment: ``df.loc[df[0] == "xyz"]``. I'm practicing with dummy data on my end. Which might be different from what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that *df* contains:

```
    Aa   Bb   Cc   Dd
0  xyz  abc  xyz  efg
1   e1   e2   e3   e4
2   f1   f2   f3   f4
```

To generate a *bool* vector (actually a *Series*) checking whether
consecutive cells in row *0* == *'xyz'*, you can run:

```
df.iloc[0] == 'xyz'
```

The result is:

```
Aa     True
Bb    False
Cc     True
Dd    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

To get the names of columns of interest, run:

```
df.columns[df.iloc[0] == 'xyz']
```

The result is:

```
Index(['Aa', 'Cc'], dtype='object')
```

So to get your expected result, retrieve *df[...]* with the above
expression between brackets:

```
df[df.columns[df.iloc[0] == 'xyz']]
```

The result is:

```
    Aa   Cc
0  xyz  xyz
1   e1   e3
2   f1   f3
```

## A comment concerning your code samples

Your first code sample - `df[0] == 'xyz'` failed because `df[0]`
attempts to retrieve a column with name *0*.
Since your DataFrame doesn't contain such column, a *KeyError: 0*
exception is raised.

The second code sample - `df[df.loc[0] == 'xyz']` is a better approach.
Note that `df.loc[0] == 'xyz'` is just what I proposed.

The reason of failure is that you now attempt something like
*boolean indexing* on columns, but in this case it does not work.
Between brackets you can pass a list of column names, not a list of
"boolean indicators".

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. How would you add more conditions? Like say you also wanted to include a column ```df[df.columns[df.iloc[0] == 'xyz']] and df[1]``` or another condition like ```df.loc[0] == "xyz" and df.loc[1] == "abc"]```?

Comment: Yes. Try on your own to run the code between brackets (e.g. *df.iloc[0] == 'xyz' and df.iloc[1] == 'abc'*) and you will see the *bool* vector which colums meet your condition. Then put this code in the whole code, to retrieve these columns.

Comment: I get ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Comment: The reason is the operators precedence. Change the code in my previous comment to *df.iloc[0].eq('xyz') & df.iloc[1].eq('abc')*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that. I'm using dummy data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods = 10, freq = "D"), 
                  "y": range(10), 
                  "z": range(10, 20), 
                   "w": range(10, 30, 2)
                  })
                 
print(df)

==>
           x  y   z   w
0 2020-01-01  0  10  10
1 2020-01-02  1  11  12
2 2020-01-03  2  12  14
3 2020-01-04  3  13  16
4 2020-01-05  4  14  18
...
```

I would now like to get only the columns that have '10' in the first row.

```
cols = (df.iloc[0] == 10)

new_df = df.loc[:, cols[cols].index]
print(new_df)


   ==>
        z   w
    0  10  10
    1  11  12
    2  12  14
    3  13  16
    4  14  18
    ...
```